# Conditional Probability Sample Space (Venn Diagram)

Tags: probability

discussion posted 6 minutes ago by KarimHabashy

Hello All,

I would like to point out (please tell me if I am wrong) the difference between the sequential events and one time event for conditional probability. As an example:

1) let P(A) be the probability that a drawn card is heart from a well shuffled deck and P(B) is the probability that its red. So what is P(A|B) ,it is 1/2. It is like saying what is the probability that the card I drew is a heart given that it is a red. Also, P(B|A) is 1. We can say that A is a subset of B.

2) let P(A) be the probability that the first card drawn is a heart and P(B) that the second card drawn is a red. Now things are totally different. P(A|B) is 25/102 and P(25/51). And we can not draw a Venn diagram for this case, because it is a time dependent sequential event. Can someone tell me if P(A and B) is the same for both cases where the first case I draw a heart first and the second case I draw a red first ?

All the Venn diagrams I saw treat 2) as 1) and I believe it is confusing. If I am wrong please point out where.

Thanks in advance.